# Serverless flask python application - No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath' when using Numpy

Tags: python, aws-lambda, serverless

The numpy package fails to import when running in the lambda function after deploying. I am not sure what the issue is but the numpy module simply just fails to finish importing with the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'
```

the outputted versions are as follows:

```
* The Python version is: Python3.9 from "/var/lang/bin/python3.9"
* The NumPy version is: "1.22.0"
```

I am making use of Serverless Python Requirements in order to add packages to the lambda function.

I have already attempted to change python versions from 3.8 to 3.9 and the numpy versions from 1.23.3 to 1.22.0 but it seems numpy fails to import regardless.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was being triggered by the numpy module not importing correctly inside of lambda at runtime.

This was caused by the incorrect architecture being used to deploy the lambda function, as my local setup did not match the environment lambda operates in.

I used a docker image to solve this and the module imported properly and the function behaved.